# PHP validate form-datam, and insert to SQL, but img is not required

Tags: php, sql, forms, validation

I am making a ticketing system, and when an user upload a ticket, she/he can upload an image, it is recommended, but not required.
When the user send the ticket with an image, validate is work fine, but without image same validate run and got "file-extension error"....
What am i doing wrong?

> PHP code

```
if ( !isset($_POST['upload_ticket']) ) {
    if ( (empty($_POST['type'])) || ($_POST['categ'] == "") || (empty($_POST['title'])) || (empty($_POST['value'])) ) {
        echo 'Töltse ki a mezőket!';
    } else {
        if ( !empty($_FILES['image']) ) {
            $user_id = $_SESSION[__SITE_ID__]['users']['id'];
            $type = $_POST['type'];
            $categ = $_POST['categ'];
            $title = trim($_POST['title']);
            $title = ucfirst($title);
            $title = htmlspecialchars($title, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
            $value = trim($_POST['value']);
            $value = ucfirst($value);
            $value = htmlspecialchars($value, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
            $reg_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

            if ( is_dir('Pictures/' . date('Ymd') . '/') ) {
                $path = 'Pictures/' . date('Ymd') . '/';
            } else {
                $path = mkdir('Pictures/' . date('Ymd') . '/');
            }
            $image_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
            $image_size = $_FILES['image']['size'];
            $image_tmp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
            $image_type = $_FILES['image']['type'];
            $image_ext = strtolower(end(explode('.',$image_name)));

            $expensions = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif');
            $target_file = $path . basename($image_name);
            $imgext = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
            if ( in_array($image_ext,$expensions) === false){
                echo 'JPG, JPEG, PNG, GIF megengedett';
            } else if ( $image_size > 2097152 ) {
                echo 'Túl nagy a kép! Max 2 MB';
            } else {
                move_uploaded_file($image_tmp, $target_file);
                $userquery = "INSERT INTO [gyakornok].[dbo].[t_tickets]";
                $userquery .= " (user_id, type, categ_id, status_id, title, value, image, reg_date)";
                $userquery .= " VALUES ('$user_id', '$type', (SELECT id FROM t_status WHERE value='Aktív') , '$categ', '$title', '$value', '$target_file','$reg_date')";
                $userquery = sqlsrv_query($conn, $userquery);
                echo 'Sikeresen elküldte a bejegyzését';
            }   
        } else {
            $user_id = $_SESSION[__SITE_ID__]['users']['id'];
            $type = $_POST['type'];
            $categ = $_POST['categ'];
            $title = trim($_POST['title']);
            $title = ucfirst($title);
            $title = htmlspecialchars($title, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
            $value = trim($_POST['value']);
            $value = ucfirst($value);
            $value = htmlspecialchars($value, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
            $reg_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

            $userquery = "INSERT INTO [gyakornok].[dbo].[t_tickets]";
            $userquery .= " (user_id, type, categ_id, status_id, title, value, reg_date)";
            $userquery .= " VALUES ('$user_id', '$type', (SELECT id FROM t_status WHERE value='Aktív') , '$categ', '$title', '$value', '$reg_date')";
            $userquery = sqlsrv_query($conn, $userquery);
            echo 'Sikeresen elküldte a bejegyzését';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So it must be getting a `$_FILES['image']` array even if nothing has been added. Try testing `if ( !empty($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']) )`

Comment: Thanks man, this is work for me. :) HUGE HUG

Answer (score 0):

I beleive this is the correct way of handling what you need...

I changed `if (!isset($_POST['upload_ticket']) )` to `if (isset($_POST['upload_ticket']) )`so the form is actually detected if submitted.

Then added `elseif( empty($_FILES['image']) )` so the form will be submitted normally if there is no image.

```
<?
if (isset($_POST['upload_ticket']) ) {

    if ( (empty($_POST['type'])) || ($_POST['categ'] == "") || (empty($_POST['title'])) || (empty($_POST['value'])) ) {
            echo 'Töltse ki a mezőket!';

    } else {

        if ( !empty($_FILES['image']) ) {
            $user_id = $_SESSION[__SITE_ID__]['users']['id'];
            $type = $_POST['type'];
            $categ = $_POST['categ'];
            $title = trim($_POST['title']);
            $title = ucfirst($title);
            $title = htmlspecialchars($title, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
            $value = trim($_POST['value']);
            $value = ucfirst($value);
            $value = htmlspecialchars($value, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
            $reg_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

            if ( is_dir('Pictures/' . date('Ymd') . '/') ) {
                $path = 'Pictures/' . date('Ymd') . '/';
            } else {
                $path = mkdir('Pictures/' . date('Ymd') . '/');
            }
            $image_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
            $image_size = $_FILES['image']['size'];
            $image_tmp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
            $image_type = $_FILES['image']['type'];
            $image_ext = strtolower(end(explode('.',$image_name)));

            $expensions = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif');
            $target_file = $path . basename($image_name);
            $imgext = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
            if ( in_array($image_ext,$expensions) === false){
                echo 'JPG, JPEG, PNG, GIF megengedett
';
            } else if ( $image_size > 2097152 ) {
                echo 'Túl nagy a kép! Max 2 MB
';
            } else {
                move_uploaded_file($image_tmp, $target_file);
                $userquery = "INSERT INTO [gyakornok].[dbo].[t_tickets]";
                $userquery .= " (user_id, type, categ_id, status_id, title, value, image, reg_date)";
                $userquery .= " VALUES ('$user_id', '$type', (SELECT id FROM t_status WHERE value='Aktív') , '$categ', '$title', '$value', '$target_file','$reg_date')";
                $userquery = sqlsrv_query($conn, $userquery);
                echo 'Sikeresen elküldte a bejegyzését
';
            }   
        } elseif( empty($_FILES['image']) ) {

            $user_id = $_SESSION[__SITE_ID__]['users']['id'];
            $type = $_POST['type'];
            $categ = $_POST['categ'];
            $title = trim($_POST['title']);
            $title = ucfirst($title);
            $title = htmlspecialchars($title, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
            $value = trim($_POST['value']);
            $value = ucfirst($value);
            $value = htmlspecialchars($value, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
            $reg_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

            $userquery = "INSERT INTO [gyakornok].[dbo].[t_tickets]";
            $userquery .= " (user_id, type, categ_id, status_id, title, value, reg_date)";
            $userquery .= " VALUES ('$user_id', '$type', (SELECT id FROM t_status WHERE value='Aktív') , '$categ', '$title', '$value', '$reg_date')";
            $userquery = sqlsrv_query($conn, $userquery);

            echo 'Sikeresen elküldte a bejegyzését';
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Correct me if I'm wrong please, and I will double check.

Comment: So what have you changed? A little explanation is always a good idea

Comment: Well first of all, how could you submit a form when you where saying if (!isset($_POST['upload_ticket']) ) ? I removed the "!" so it will detect the form submitted, then added elseif( empty($_FILES['image']) ) so the form will be submitted normally if there is no "Image". I think actually reading the code you can see what I changed. -_-

Comment: Done boss, anything else ?

Comment: Simpler than you thought

Comment: It might be a solution what you gave him, but that`s not the way you handle forms...

Comment: As OP did not show us the form, and said that when a file was provided it all worked OK, what you **cannot assume** is that just because the code looks odd you can arbitrarily amend whatever you like.

Comment: Yes yes, I can assume that the code is bugged, since it`s badly structured and written. I bet it would not pass a unit testing. lol